# Visual Basic rename a group of files

Tags: vb.net, visual-studio-2012, file-rename

I'm starting with Visual Basic and use Visual Studio 2012 and trying to make a tool for renaming a group of files.

How it shoul be:

1- With the "Select Files" button, I can choose the files and they are listed in the ListBox

2- "Old value" is a textbox and is the value to be changed in the filename. For example: fff

3- "New value" is a textbox and is the new value that should replace the old. For example: zzz

4- Rename is a button to start the process.

To rename only one file it's not a problem.
But how to rename all the files from the ListBox which are containing the Oldvalue ?

Can you please help me!

Thanks

Comment: Show us what you have tried.

Comment: Code is as new answer.

Answer (score 0):

I suggest looping over the selected files in the listbox, checking to see which ones contain the OldValue string.

You could use string.contains http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dy85x1sa(v=vs.110).aspx?cs-save-lang=1&cs-lang=vb#code-snippet-1

Sounds like you have the replace function sorted since you say it's no problem to do just one file.

Comment: Thanks @70Mike
I add my code as new answer because it's too long for a comment.

Answer (score 0):

Thank you 70Mike.

But I have some problem with the loop.
If it works only for 1 file and not for all.

Here is my code:

```
Public Class frmRename

Private Sub cmdSelectFile_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles cmdSelectFile.Click

    If (OpenFileDialog1.ShowDialog = Windows.Forms.DialogResult.OK) Then
        For Each S As String In OpenFileDialog1.FileNames
            lstSelectFiles.Items.Add(S)
        Next
    Else : Exit Sub
    End If

End Sub

Private Sub cmdRename_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles cmdRename.Click

    Try
        For LC As Integer = 0 To lstSelectFiles.Items.Count - 1

            Dim s1 As String = lstSelectFiles.Items(LC)
            Dim s2 As String = txtbOld.Text
            Dim b As String
            b = s1.Contains(s2)
            Console.WriteLine("Is the string, s2, in the string, s1?: {0}", b)

            Do While b = True

                Dim oldFile As String = lstSelectFiles.Items(LC)
                Dim newFile As String = Replace(lstSelectFiles.Items(LC), txtbOld.Text, txtbNew.Text)

                If File.Exists(oldFile) And Not File.Exists(newFile) Then
                    File.Move(oldFile, newFile)
                    Kill(oldFile)

                End If
            Loop

        Next

    Catch ex As Exception
        MsgBox("No file renamed")
    End Try

End Sub
End Class
```

Comment: Does someone have an ideo about the Loop?